# How to insert data multiple times in a table (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have 3 tables as follows:

`DXBusinessPolicy_Policy`

| ID | Code | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COMBO.2103001 | [Giá nền] T9/2020 #1 |
| 2 | IPTV-0121.002 | [Giá nền] T8/2020 #1 |

`DXBusinessPolicy_Service`

| ID | Code | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INT | Internet |
| 2 | IPTV | IPTV |
| 3 | CMR | Camera |
| 4 | FSAFE | Fsafe |

`DXBusinessPolicy_PolicyService`

| ID | PolicyID | ServiceID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertPolicyService
    @id int,
    @services varchar(1000) //This is Service Name
AS 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO dbo.DXBusinessPolicy_PolicyService (PolicyID, ServiceID) 
        SELECT 
            @id,
            (SELECT dbo.DXBusinessPolicy_Service.ID 
             FROM dbo.DXBusinessPolicy_Service
             WHERE dbo.DXBusinessPolicy_Service.Code IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@services, ',')))
END 



EXEC InsertPolicyService 2, 'FSAFE,CMR'
```

I want to insert Policy ID 2 with service named FSAFE and CMR into table DXBusinessPolicy_PolicyService.

I tried to execute this stored procedure, but I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My expectation is:

`DXBusinessPolicy_PolicyService`

| ID | PolicyID | ServiceID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |

Comment: I strongly recommend you use a Table Valued Parameter, instead of splitting a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner sub-query returns multiple results, which isn't possible when its a sub-query. However you don't need that many queries, just the one:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DXBusinessPolicy_PolicyService (PolicyID, ServiceID) 
    SELECT @id, dbo.DXBusinessPolicy_Service.ID 
    FROM dbo.DXBusinessPolicy_Service
    WHERE dbo.DXBusinessPolicy_Service.Code IN (
        SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@services,','))
    );
```